# Google Sheets Copying Conditional Formatting while adjusting formulas

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet that uses Conditional Formatting using a formula.

So, for the cell range B2:C2, I have the following formula assigned: =if(B2<100,if(C2<80, true,false),false)

This highlights B2 & C2 if B2 is less than 100 AND C2 is less than 80.

This works.

Now, I want to do this for a bunch of rows. However, if I use either copy/paste special or format painter, it does not translate the formula in the conditional formatting to indicate the new row. They all reference row 2.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to manually add Conditional Formatting to every row?

Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change range to `B2:C` and forumula to:

```
=($B2<100)*($C2<80)
```

[image]